# Google WebSpeech API is throwing 'not-allowed' error for microphone permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition, httpserver

I am using Google's WebSpeech API found on this site:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API

With Python's http.server on my Windows machine, 
[image]

it works without any problem:
[image]

I upload exactly same files, same API but it does not work in my CentOS remote server throwing a 'not-allowed' error for the microphone permission:
[image]

I thought that problem could be http server related. So I tried with Apache Httpd, Python http.server and Nginx. None of them worked.

Any idea about what's blocking the microphone? 
Thanks!

Comment: As a workaround to this problem, I installed a self-signed SSL certificate to the remote server allowing me to use https. 
This way, microphone has become allowed to use in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find documentation backing this up, but from my own experience I can confirm that only after installing an SSL certificate on a website, chrome stopped blocking it from requesting microphone access.

Comment: I could experience that with an Angular app, while using `ng serve` via http, an error 'not-allowed' was fired. Switching to SSL with the '--ssl' option fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced `not-allowed` also - trying to access mic from Chrome inside cross-origin iframe.  Resolved by adding `allow="microphone;"` to the iframe:

```
<iframe src="mysrc" allow="microphone;"></iframe>
```

Note: Also required using HTTPS for parent page & iframe page

Reference: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue (throws `not-allowed`), but I was using HTTPS.

In my case, it turned out that you can't obtain speech or enable microphone access from an `iframe`. The same code works normally when not shown in an iframe.